# what's the meaning of "Am i on jerk'd?"" in this context- 7th episode of "Big Mouth" , an American adult animated sitcom

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

- What the hell are you gonna jerk off to? - Nothing.
  I guess I'm not gonna jerk off.
  [BREATHLESS LAUGH.]
  Yeah, you're you're not gonna jerk off.
  All right, where are the cameras? [CHUCKLES.]
  **Am I on Jerk'd?** [LAUGHS.]
- Where's Mark McGrath? - Hey, I'm serious.

Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=big-mouth-2017&episode=s01e07

Comment: I am sure questions about juvenile 'adult' (pornographic) videos are off-topic. If they aren't, they should be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about masturbation.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think *this question* is about that, although some of the words mentioned in it are. There's a show called *Punk'd*, where basically there's a hidden camera and famous people are essentially "pranked". *Jerk'd* might be an allusion to that show.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, I can't find a good dictionary definition for "on" with the meaning "to be **on** a television program".

> All right, where are the cameras? Am I on Jerk'd?

The character is alluding to a TV show called "Jerk'd", which probably doesn't exist. This is most likely a reference to "Punk'd", as userr2684291 says. It's common for people who realise they're on a hidden camera show to ask "Where is the camera? Is that a camera? Am I being filmed? Am I on TV-Show-X?", etc.

See [Hidden cameras in reality television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_camera#In_reality_television).

Comment: Some dictionaries list _on television_ as a separate idiom (see [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20television), e.g.).

Comment: @J.R. "to be on television" isn't exactly the same as "to be on {name of program}" where the program is a TV or radio program. I did find definitions for "on (the) television".